# Azure Devops REST API with C# Authentication

Tags: c#, rest, azure-devops

In my place of work we have our own azure devops server for source control
I've written a C# application that interacts with it using REST calls with the HttpClient class
Everything works fine but at the moment I have to use a personal access token for my API calls to work

I couldn't find any other solution that I can implement (or at least that I understand HOW to implement) other than that as I don't have administrator privileges on that server

I was wondering... How is it that when I make GET calls from my internet explorer and get the json response but I can't implement the same behavior in my C# HtppClient calls?

Is it possible to use my windows credentials as authentication to the azure devops REST API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the solution was quite simple
I added UseDefaultCredentials to the constructor of HttpClient like that:

```
            client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true }); ;
```

and that actually works!
All my REST calls work without using PAT at all

Comment: Hello @AshChlor, even I am facing same issue and trying to access Azure devops API using current login user, and even after using above code i get error as "Non-Authoritative Information". Can you please update with more detail code you have used.